# Multidimensional lambda numpy frompyfunc?

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a way to use numpy frompyfunc() with multidimensional arrays while mixing the components?

To explain further consider the code

```
uadd = np.frompyfunc(lambda x, y: [x[0] + y[1],x[1] + y[0]] , 2, 1)
uadd.accumulate([[1,2], [3,4]])
```

I would hope, that this would work in such a way that the first part of the list `[1,2]` would be added to the second part `[3,4]` and the other way around resulting in `[ [1,2][0] + [3,4][1] , [ [1,2][1] + [3,4][0]] == [1+3,2+4] == [4,6]`. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Your second operation is just 'np.array([1.2])+np.array([3,4])`, but I don't understand how this relates to the first two lines.

Comment: +1, The first line was not supposed to be there. I understand that we can perform such an  operation quite easily in a different way. This more of a conceptual question.

Comment: Well, you would USE your created function just by saying `uadd(...)`, not `uadd.accumulate`, but it won't get the parameters the way you expect.

Comment: So what did that code do?

Comment: `frompyfunc` is for a function that takes scalar inputs.  Your function expects x and y to be 2 element somethings, not scalars.

Comment: It's unclear. I guess it's because you don't understand [the Numpy ufunc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/ufuncs.html). See [ask]. Do a preliminary research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function with a diagnostic print:

```
In [286]: def foo(x,y):
     ...:     print(f'x is {x}, y is {y}')
     ...:     return [x[0] + y[1],x[1] + y[0]]
     ...:     

In [287]: uadd = np.frompyfunc(foo , 2, 1)

In [288]: uadd([1,2], [3,4])
x is 1, y is 3
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

`frompyfunc` pass the int `1` to `foo`, not some sort of array.

Here's a legit use of `frompyfunc`, with an function that takes 2 (scalar) arguments, and returns 1 `object`:

```
In [266]: f=np.frompyfunc(lambda x,y: x+10*y, 2,1)
```

With a pair of arguments that broadcast together:

```
In [267]: f(np.arange(3)[:,None], np.arange(2))
Out[267]: 
array([[0, 10],
       [1, 11],
       [2, 12]], dtype=object)
```

As a `ufunc` it does have a `reduce`, and an `accumulate` (think of this a generalization of `np.cumsum`):

```
In [268]: f.reduce(np.arange(5))
Out[268]: 100

In [269]: f.accumulate(np.arange(5))
Out[269]: array([0, 10, 30, 60, 100], dtype=object)
```

`np.vectorize` has a (slower) `signature` option that allows passing "arrays" to the function, `np.frompyfunc` does not.  Though I suppose you could play some games with object dtype inputs.

```
In [276]: f(np.array((np.array((10,20)),(30,40,50)),object), np.array((11,(3,4)),object))
Out[276]: 
array([array([120, 130]),
       (30, 40, 50, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4)],
      dtype=object)
```

Defining an object dtype array, containing a tuple and list:

```
In [289]: x = np.empty(2,object); x[0]=(1,2); x[1]=[3,4]
```

then your `uadd` works:

```
In [290]: uadd(x,x)
x is (1, 2), y is (1, 2)
x is [3, 4], y is [3, 4]
Out[290]: array([list([3, 3]), list([7, 7])], dtype=object)
```

and even the accumulate:

```
In [291]: uadd.accumulate((x,x))
x is (1, 2), y is (1, 2)
x is [3, 4], y is [3, 4]
Out[291]: 
array([[(1, 2), list([3, 4])],
       [list([3, 3]), list([7, 7])]], dtype=object)
```